# Why is impedance divided by 3 for an induction motor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, induction-motor

> A 50 Hz, 5 pole pare, 400 V (line-to-line), star-connected, 585
> min-1 squirrel cage induction machine has the following resistance
> and reactance per phase (referred to the stator): R1=0.5 Ω R’2=0.7 Ω
> and X1=X’2=3 Ω.

> (a) Calculate the current, active and reactive power absorbed
> from the network if the motor rotates at nominal speed.

I have been provided MATLAB code for the answer but I am unsure why Ztot is divided by 3. Could usage of conjugate be explained also. I drew the per phase model with Vline divided by sqrt(3) and had impedance apart from that division.

Can someone provided a more visual representation of answer by calculating P and Q separately rather than using S?

```
s=((3000/5)-585)/(3000/5)
zmotor=(0.5+0.7/s+6*1i)/3
I1=(400/sqrt(3))/zmotor
abs(I1)
angle(I1)*180/pi
S=400/sqrt(3)*conj(I1)*3
```

Comment: Do you understand what star-connected means?  Or per phase model?

Comment: star connected yes. vph = vline / root3 and iph=Il. per phase is where i imagine division from 3 comes but never seen before

Comment: Machine has a total apparent power, but three windings, so when you break it down you divide by 3 to get impedance / phase.